# issue with checking already existing values in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check of the values in my 3 textfield already exist in my table before proceeding further in my statement but it does not work in eclipse but work in heidisql? prepareStatement and resultset are properlt initislise at the top.

I already try using ? and preStatement.setString(1, get_status_update) but it gave me the same error result.

```
String get_status_update = stats_status_txta.getText();
        String get_username= friend_username_txtf.getText();
        String get_friendname= friend_list_txta.getText();

        DB_connection db_connection = new DB_connection(); 

            try{

                if(get_username.length() < 3) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(statusPanel,"You need to insert a username here","Post Lodge Status Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                } else if (get_status_update.length() < 3) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(statusPanel,"Please insert the status update you wish to like","Post Lodge Status Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                } else {

                    String sql = " SELECT sut.status_update_id, up.user_id , fd.friend_id "
                            + "FROM tb_logde_status_update as tsu "
                            + "INNER JOIN status_update_tb as sut ON sut.status_update_id = tsu.status_update_id "
                            + "INNER JOIN user_profile as up ON tsu.user_id = up.user_id "
                            + "INNER JOIN friend_details as fd ON tsu.friend_id = fd.friend_id "
                            + "WHERE sut.status_update_msg='"+get_status_update+"' AND up.username='"+get_username+"' AND fd.friend_username='"+get_friendname+"' ";

                    preStatement = db_connection.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

                    res = preStatement.executeQuery();

                    boolean send_logde_status = false;

                            while (res.next()) {
                                if(res.getString("status_update_msg").equalsIgnoreCase(get_status_update) 
                                        && res.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase(get_username) 
                                        && res.getString("friend_username").equalsIgnoreCase(get_friendname)) {

                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(statusPanel, "Status update has already been like by you, choose another one!");
                                    send_logde_status = true;

                                    break; // Get out of the loop. No more need for it.
```

// Maybe the error is around here?

```
        } 
    } ...
```

When I use the query directly from the database query it work!

```
SELECT sut.status_update_id, up.user_id , fd.friend_id
FROM tb_logde_status_update as tsu
INNER JOIN status_update_tb as sut ON sut.status_update_id = tsu.status_update_id
INNER JOIN user_profile as up ON tsu.user_id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN friend_details as fd ON tsu.friend_id = fd.friend_id
WHERE sut.status_update_msg="not hallo world" AND up.username="username" AND fd.friend_username="paul";
```

I am inserting the exactly values from my 3 textfields. I am getting the status_update_id, user_id, friend_id when i use the query from the database but not in my action listener button

**Error:** Column 'status_update_msg' not found.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Munging query strings with parameters can lead to inexplicable syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: it does not work even if I use =? and preStatement.setString(1, get_status_update), didn't I already say that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parameters are not exactly the same as the ones passed in the direct query, I would suggest the following:

- Log the parameters values in console
- Try using `trim()` and/or `toLowerCase()` if parameter values need to be in lower case only

Also, using `setXXX()` methods for `preparedStatement` is better approach than appending parameter values to a String query.

Comment: how do I log the parameters in console?

Comment: Just use log4j or slf4j or Sysout?

Comment: yes. Space might be the issue as mentioned by @Darshan Mehta. Put syout like System.out.println("-"+value+"-") and check whether there is any blank space coming between dashes

Comment: My value come out like this WHERE sut.status_update_msg='not hallo world' AND up.username='username' AND fd.friend_username='paul'

Comment: Could you print the `sql` and try comparing it to the query that you are executing in MySQL?